# How to fix `Vue is not defined` in Vue 3 + Vue router 4?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I discovered a bug in PrimeVue and wanted to create a reproduceable for them to investigate on it. However I am facing yet another problem that VueRouter is not working in my sample code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-router-failed?file=src%2Fmain.js

I got this

```
Error in /turbo_modules/vue-router@4.0.3/dist/vue-router.global.js (3255:7)
Vue is not defined
```

I found some solution but seems they are Vue 2 related. How to solve this in Vue3?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you get any thing working ?

Comment: @AbhinavKumar I have not but one of the user shown me codesandbox.io is working. https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-butterfly-ej23l?file=/src/App.vue